# Turn STM32F4 Discovery into an HID USB device

Tags: stm32

I'm getting an STM32F4 Discovery board delivered this week, and busy snooping around for ways to turn the device into a USB HID device.

I basically want to write a simple application that will allow me to register/configure the board as a HID input device, so my PC can recognise it as a game controller, with one button, connected to the "User Button" on the board.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ST provides ready made code for having an HID device. It might need to be a bit customized depending on what you want, but 80-90% is already done. Take a look at their website.

Look at the [STM32F4](http://www.st.com/internet/mcu/product/252146.jsp) page for that particular device. Tons of examples.